# View syntax errors from an external CQL script?

Tags: cassandra, cql, datastax, cqlsh, cassandra-2.1

I am wondering if there is a simple way to view any syntax errors that may have been present in a .cql script that I run through cqlsh?

I have created several scripts with a huge number of `INSERT` statements to load data into my Cassandra db. To create the scripts I did a find/replace using notepad++ to prep the file (Yes, in hindsight I should have just wrote a Python script).

I know that there should be 7,500 records after I run the script, but there are only 7,483 - I suspect that some of the `INSERT`statements aren't properly formatted (since I hacked the statements together) but I don't get any feedback from cqlsh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest trying [DataStax DevCenter](http://www.datastax.com/what-we-offer/products-services/devcenter). It's a free tool (after registering on the website). It's a bit more of an IDE type experience where it will highlight syntax errors as you type. You could try pasting in your giant script and see what it shows.

The other thing I would check is to make sure you don't have any duplicates based on your primary key definition.

Comment: Thanks for the help, really wish i would have know about the DevCenter tool beforehand!

Comment: Turns out the issue was with duplicate primary keys but it took me awhile to figure it out. My primary key was  `PRIMARY KEY (date, time)` - which should have had any duplicates since each date had one 1 entry for every hour. Since i stripped out the formatting so that it was only numeric and I was inserting them into the table as doubles. I didn't realize that by default CQL has a default float_precision of 5, which was truncating the values when they would get inserted into the table. I never ran the statements in DevCenter so i am not sure if it would have caught the issue or not.